why am i getting this error when using FFmpeg in a spring boot app on a mac intel device: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000013d71b0e0, pid=49777, tid=42755
I am working with FFmpeg library in spring boot app to stream live recording from an ip camera via RSTP and save to S3 bucket but i am running into the error below.
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000013d71b0e0, pid=49777, tid=42755
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-19.0.2.7.1 (19.0.2+7) (build 19.0.2+7-FR)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-19.0.2.7.1 (19.0.2+7-FR, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [libavutil.56.dylib+0xa0e0]  av_strstart+0x10
No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/Users/CODA/Desktop/videoSaleService/hs_err_pid49777.log
If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
https://github.com/corretto/corretto-19/issues/
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    try (S3Client s3Client = S3Client.create()) {
        VideoService videoService = new VideoService(new VideoRepositoryImpl(),
                new S3Service(s3Client), new VideoExtractor(client), new ISApiClient());
        videoService.streamLiveVideoRSTP(System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error occurred while streaming live video: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unexpected error occurred: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void streamLiveVideoRSTP(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("live_stream", ".mp4");

    try (InputStream inputStream = client.getLiveStreamingVideoRSTP();
         OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occurred while streaming live video: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new IOException("Error occurred while streaming live video", e);
    }

    // Upload the captured video file to S3
    try {
        uploadStreamedVideoToS3(tempFile);
    } finally {
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            if (!tempFile.delete()) {
                log.warn("Failed to delete temporary file: {}", tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}

private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> frameQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

public ISApiClient() {
    new Thread(this::startGrabbingFrames).start();
}

public InputStream getLiveStreamingVideoRSTP() {
    return new InputStream() {
        private ByteArrayInputStream currentStream;

        @Override
        public int read() {
            if (currentStream == null || currentStream.available() == 0) {
                byte[] frame = frameQueue.poll();
                if (frame != null) {
                    currentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(frame);
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return currentStream.read();
        }
    };
}

private void startGrabbingFrames() {
    try (FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(rtspUrl)) {
        frameGrabber.setOption("rtsp_transport", "tcp");
        frameGrabber.start();

        FFmpegFrameFilter frameFilter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("format=yuv420p",
                frameGrabber.getImageWidth(), frameGrabber.getImageHeight());
        frameFilter.setPixelFormat(frameGrabber.getPixelFormat());
        frameFilter.start();

        log.info("Started grabbing frames from RTSP stream.");

        while (true) {
            Frame frame = frameGrabber.grab();
            if (frame != null && frame.image != null) {
                log.info("Frame grabbed: width={} height={} timestamp={}",
                        frame.imageWidth, frame.imageHeight, frame.timestamp);
                frameFilter.push(frame);
                Frame filteredFrame = frameFilter.pull();

                if (filteredFrame != null && filteredFrame.image != null) {
                    log.info("Frame filtered: width={} height={} timestamp={}",
                            filteredFrame.imageWidth, filteredFrame.imageHeight, filteredFrame.timestamp);
                    byte[] imageBytes = convertFrameToBytes(filteredFrame);
                    if (imageBytes.length > 0) {
                        frameQueue.offer(imageBytes);
                        log.info("Frame added to queue, queue size={}", frameQueue.size());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error grabbing frames: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private byte[] convertFrameToBytes(Frame frame) {
    if (frame == null || frame.image == null) {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
    for (Object img : frame.image) {
        if (img instanceof ByteBuffer) {
            byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) img;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (byteBuffer == null) {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytes);
    return bytes;
}

